# Undersea volcano washes deep sea limbless slime horror with a terrible appetite onto beach and into local town?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Sort of like the blob, this marauding slime with a voracious appetite was the top predator in its underwater environment (aside from a rare creature, nearly entirely made up of teeth) until a titanic underwater eruption sends it hurtling to the surface.

It makes its way into some marshes, where it feasts on snakes and frogs, until it makes its way into a local American town and is hunted back into the marshes and eventually (with fire) hounded back into the sea.

I remember that the creature was extremely sensitive to light, and could feel the light of the searching locals' torches through the black water of the swamps.

I believe this was one of a collection of short horror/sci-fi stories, and is quite an old story.

Is this ringing any bells with anyone?

Comment: Rather Lovecraftian, but I can't come up with a specific story...

Comment: It's almost certainly from the Cthulu mythos, but there are quite a few stories in that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu_Mythos_anthology

Answer (score 6):

I'm fairly certain the story is "Slime", by [Joseph Payne Brennan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Payne_Brennan):

> His best-known story, "Slime", follows a protoplasmic life form as it ascends from its home deep within the ocean and begins to prey upon coastal residents of a small New England town.

I read it in *Alfred Hitchcock's Monster Museum* many moons ago (late 70s), but according to the Wikipedia article, it's been reprinted at least 50 times.

Edit: publication info if you're interested - https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?88069

Comment: This is the exact story I thought of.

Comment: Copy of the monster museum is in the post as we speak. Thanks for the help again Raven!